# ssh login to remote server in Netbeans for PHP

Tags: php, netbeans, ssh, remote-server

im a newbie to Netbeans IDE. I have to connect to a remote server but I am having problems connecting to the server.
1)I went to File-->new project -->PHP-->app on remote server.
2)I entered the correct username and password
3)Test the Connection --> connection failed

The only thing my sysadmin replied to my query was "Its a linux login, you need to SSH".

what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

SFTP [actually uses SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol), so choose SFTP as your connection type. Your sysadmin doesn't seem to have been very helpful, however if you have access to a Linux box, or a Linux shell environment, try connecting to your server using

> ssh username@hostname

This will either prompt you for a password, or give an error message about why it couldn't log you in.

Make sure your login details are correct, and that you have the correct remote path.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried command `ssh yourusername@yourhost`?

If it works, you can on "Remont Configuration", mange "Remote Connection", "Connection Type" select "SFTP", Input your hostname, password and try again.

reference to [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).

Answer (score 0):

By default Netbeans only supports FTP ans SFTP for remote server configurations.